# Unable to boot windows 8.1 after installing Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, windows, kubuntu

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04, and I cannot boot into the previously installed Windows 8.1.
As I read everywhere, this shouldn't be a problem: Kubuntu should recognize that Windows is there. But every time I start Kubuntu boots without asking anything.

Thank you for your answers!

UPDATE:
I realized that I run a chkdsk on the Windows' partition, and I didn't let it end, so it may be marked as "unclean" as written here: [Problem to enter in NTFS partition "The disk contains an unclean file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290630/problem-to-enter-in-ntfs-partition)
Still struggling to make it work, though.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't wipe your Windows partition when installing Kubuntu?

Comment: Or did you install Kubuntu in BIOS/CSM mode and have system set to boot only in CSM mode? Windows has to boot in UEFI on mode. And the two are not really compatible, so once you start booting in one mode you cannot change. Or if Kubuntu is CSM mode you cannot boot Windows in UEFI mode from grub menu. Boot-Repair can convert install to UEFI mode if you did install in BIOS/CSM mode.

Comment: I don't believe Boot Repair is necessary to do the conversion. A simple installation of grub-efi should fix the problem. I agree that this is most likely a BIOS/EFI boot mixing issue. As a clarification, on my EFI (Lenovo) there is an option under the Boot tab called Boot Mode or something to that effect with the options "UEFI" and "Legacy". Legacy is the CSM/BIOS mode and UEFI is EFI mode.

Comment: It is also, of course, possible that SecureBoot was turned off which would also prevent Windows 8 from booting. However if I remember correctly it simply prints out an error message saying that SecureBoot is off and does not continue the boot processes.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue with the following command:

```
sudo update-grub2
```